# How do I post an String Array with MockMvc?

Tags: spring, junit, mockmvc

I am currently working on a Spring project and I want to write some tests. Unfortunately I don't know how to pass the requiered Array. 
The Get Request works just fine... Here is my Code: 
MainControllerTest.java

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private MainController controller;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .build();
}

@Test
public void resetAll() throws Exception {

    String[] players = new String[] {"Player 1", "Player 2"};

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8443/api/reset")
    )
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("false"));


    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("http://localhost:8443/api/player").content(players)
    ); 
}
```

MainController.java

```
@PostMapping("/player")
public void setPlayersList(@RequestBody String[] players) {
    for(int i = 0; i<players.length; i++) {
        playersList.add(players[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(playersList.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: Your method expects an integer. Why would you send an array? And why do you use a POST to GET a list of questions? Oh, and the URL is completely different, too? Post the **relevant** code.

Comment: Post the code for the /api/player endpoint

Comment: I am sorry, but now it's the right code.

Comment: Your server expect a JSON document representing an array of strings, right? So you need to send a JSON doculent representing an array of strings, and set the content type to application/json. Also, drop the `http://localhost:8443`.

Comment: But from the frontend it receives a normal Array in the form of: ["Player 1", "Player 2"]

Comment: JB Nizet is right, you need to provide JSON as a String, not array of strings. You can use Jackson's ObjectMapper and writeValueAsString method. When you call your service from frontend your request was converted to JSON String behind the scene. Latter, Jackson library converted that JSON to you String[].

Answer (score 0):

Late answer is better than no answer at all. Here is code that could do the trick. Here cacheNames is `Array<String>` and also in Controller requested this type.

```
mockMvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/endpoint")
        .queryParams(
            LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
                .apply { this.addAll(Controller.PARAMETER, parameters.toList()) }
        )
).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
```

Note for Java: `.apply` is the same as create an instance and then call `.addAll` with it.